# RANK values per column with AWK

Tags: awk, rank

Is there a RANK function in AWK that RANKs values per column in a single text file (higher value ranks on top)? Expecting this:

```
Original       Results
A  B  C     Result_A  Result_B Result_C
8  5  4     1          2          1
4  7  3     2          1          2
2  3  4     3          3          1
```

I'm using this AWK script but only Ranks a single column. Can anyone guide me to the right direction? Very appreciated.

```
awk ' {
if(val!=$2){ rank++; }
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",rank,$1,$2)
val=$2
} ' <(sort -k2 -nr Original.txt) > Results.txt
```

Comment: why `Result_C` has order `1 2 1`, shouldn't it be `1 3 2` according to `4 3 4` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Original column C has values 4 3 4 where 4 (duplicate) is the higher value therefore should be rank top 1 and value 3 should be 2. Hope this make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `gawk` and `asorti` function [Array-Sorting-Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions)

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
    NR==1{
        for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) printf "Result_%s%s", $i, i==NF?ORS:OFS 
        next
    }
    { for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) M[i, NR-1]=$i }
    END{
        for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i){
            delete d;
            for(j=1; j<=NR-1; ++j) d[M[i,j]]
            n = asorti(d, idx)
            for(j=1; j<=n; ++j) rank[i, idx[j]] = n-j+1
        }
        for(j=1; j<=NR-1; ++j)
            for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
                printf "%s%s", rank[i, M[i,j]], i==NF?ORS:OFS
    }
' original
```

you get,

```
Result_A    Result_B    Result_C
1   2   1
2   1   2
3   3   1
```

Comment: Ricardo Have you tried? Hmm I'm getting syntax errors on line 3 and illegal statement on 16.

Comment: @user2150845 I use `gnu-awk` a `awk` flavor ..... I said it in the first paragraph

Comment: Ricardo You're absolutely right. Works perfect! Thanks a lot