# AWK assign upper value for rank assignment during tie

Tags: shell, awk

I'm working on rank assignment to a list of values that is sorted in a file.

A miniature example is

Input:

```
1
2
2
2
3
4
```

Instead of normal ranking when there is a tie, I need to assign the upper value. So the required output is

```
1 1
2 4  #Note that it is not 2, since we have three 2's the upper bound is 4
2 4
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

I tried something like below, but it is not consistent.

```
$ awk ' BEGIN{t=0} NR==FNR { a[$1]++; next } { print $1,a[$1]+t; t=a[$1]  } '  rank_in.txt rank_in.txt
1 1
2 4
2 6
2 6
3 4
4 2
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257349/rank-values-per-column-with-awk) does normal ranking, so this question is not duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two passes with just awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{rank[$1]=NR; next} {print $1, rank[$1]}' file file
1 1
2 4
2 4
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

or one pass with a pipe:

```
$ nl file | sort -k2,2 -k1,1nr | awk '$2!=prev{rank=$1; prev=$2} {print $2, rank}'
1 1
2 4
2 4
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

If you don't have `nl` on your system you could use `cat -n` or `awk '{print NR, $0}'` to generate the line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing a double pass or keeping track of memory, we just use a uniq and reconstruct everything:

```
uniq -c file | awk '{n=n+$1;for(i=1;i<=$1;++i) print $2,n}' -
```

Comment: thanks @kvantour.. will not uniq change the order ?.. should we sort before piping to awk?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {++fq[$1]; next} p != $1{s+=fq[$1]} {print p=$1, s}' file file

1 1
2 4
2 4
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- input data is already sorted

Sample data:

```
$ cat rank.dat
1
2
2
2
3
4
```

One `awk` idea requiring a single pass through the file:

```
awk '
function print_rank() {

for ( i=1 ; i<=cnt ; i++ )
    print id,rank
}

$1 != id { print_rank()          # if we have a new id, print last id
           cnt=0                 # reset counter
         }

         { id=$1                 # keep track of current id
           rank++                # increment rank by 1 for each new row processed
           cnt++                 # keep track of number of times we see this id
         }

END { print_rank() }             # flush last id to stdout

' rank.dat
```

This generates:

```
1 1
2 4
2 4
2 4
3 5
4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
$ awk ' NR==FNR { a[$1]++; next } { print $1, FNR + --a[$1] } ' rank_in.txt  rank_in.txt
1 1
2 4
2 4
2 4
3 5
4 6
$
```